# Error in POST$pname : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable in rapache

Tags: r, post, web, get, rapache

we are working on RApache,

we are sending the form argument from .html file which configured to brew.

_______________________(one.html)_______________

```html
<html>

<form name="one" method="POST" action="./brew/one_result.html">

<input type="text" name="one">
<input type="submit">

</html>
```

__________________________(one_result.html)_________________

```html
<%
print(post$one)
%>
```

passing of arguments from (one.html) to (one_result.html) will work some times and argument value is printing on browser but some times saying  "POST$pname : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable" in error log.

could any body help us to resolve the issue.

thanks in advance,
Mallik.

Answer (score 0):

this is the information when RApache is started

[notice] Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_R/1.2.5 R/3.2                                             .2 PHP/5.3.3 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.8.0 configured -- resuming normal operations

environment
centos - 6.7